# Difference between using wildcards and declaring generic type in abstract method in Java

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, abstract

I'm trying to understand Generic types in Java, and in theory it looks understandable, but when I need to apply it to real code I have problem. I want to declare abstract method which will return generic type. Let's assume that I have some empty interface called Magicable and 2 class implements it: Magican and Witch.
Now I wonder what is the difference between those 3 declarations:

```
/*1*/protected abstract <T extends Magicable> List<T> getMagicables();
/*2*/protected abstract List<? extends Magicable> getMagicables();
/*3*/protected abstract List<Magicable> getMagicables();
```

1. In first case I have problem when I want to implement body of this method in some class which extends the abstract class:

   ```
   @Override
   protected List<Magican> getMagicable() {..}
   ```

   I have warning message:

   > Type safety: The return type List<Magican> for getMagicable() from the type MagicanService needs unchecked conversion to conform to List<Magicable> from the type MagicableService.
2. In second case I don't have this warning, but I have problem in abstract class in which I declared above abstract method:

   ```
     public void <T extends Magicable> T getOneFromList() {
         List<T> list = getMagicables();
         //.....
     }
   ```

   In this case I have compilation error in getMagicables() call:

   > Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<capture#2-of ? extends Magicable> to List<T>
3. Third case causes compilation errors in both abovementioned places of code. I don't think if it is properly solution in my case.

Comment: `List<Witch> witches = getMagicables(Witch.class);` is doable - with 1. `(Class<T> type) .... type.cast(obj) ...`.

Comment: It's highly unlikely that #1 is a form of method anybody would ever use. Since the type argument to `T` is given by the code which calls the method and since we can't create a new instance of `T`, the only thing the method can do without some sort of unchecked cast is return an empty list. Hence why e.g. [`Collections.emptyList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#emptyList--) and similar are the only places you'll find such a method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. First case

Just declare your method with:

```
    @Override
    protected <T extends Magicable> List<T> getMagicables() {
       List<T> list = ...
       return list
    }
```

If you really want this:

```
    @Override
    protected List<Magican> getMagicable() {..}
```

you may have to declare your generic T into the class defintion

```
     public abstract class AbstractKlass<T extends Magicable> {
        protected abstract List<T> getMagicables();
     }
```

then in your Subclass:

```
     public class MySubClass extends AbstractKlass<Magican> {

        @Override
        protected List<Magican> getMagicables() {
           ...
        }
     }
```

> 2. Second case

The compilation error is normal because `<? extends Magicable>` from the signature of method means you don't care what's inside your list from the moment you can consider those elements just as Magicable. When doing a call

```
    List<T> list = getMagicables();
```

You want to take care of the type T without knowing it. In other terms, there are 3 use cases: T is Magicable (OK), T is Magician (Wrong because getMagicables may return a list of Witch) and T is Witch (Wrong too).

> 3. Why I use `? extends Magicable` instead of just `Magicable` in lists

Because `List<Magician>` is a subtype of `List<? extends Magicable>` but not a subtype of `List<Magicable>`. This is usefull for parameters of methods.

```
    public void doIt(List<? extends Magicable> list) {
         // you can't add a Magician here
    }
```

may be used as

```
    List<Witch> list = ...
    doIt(list);
```

But if you have

```
    public void doIt(List<Magicable> list) {
         // you can add a Magician here
    }
```

You can't use it as

```
    List<Witch> list = ...
    doIt(list); // compile error
```

Answer (score 1):

For the part of the problem, you did show us, method /* 3 */ is sufficient, you do not need the generics for that part of your code. But you need to respect substitutability:

You get the error in #1 because the sub-type method is restricting the range of the return type: a `Magican` is `Magicable` but not vice versa. Super-types of `Magicable` are allowed in the sub-type. The sub-type method has to be substitutable for the super-type method, which is not the case in your example.

The error in #2 is due to the nature of the wildcard `?`: `? extends Magicable` and `T extends Magicable` need not be the same type. If `T` is declared in the class scope, e.g. class `Magican<T> implements Magicable<T>` (of course your interface needs to declare T in this case) all occurrences of `T` in your type would refer to the same class.

Answer (score 1):

```
public abstract class AbstractMagicable<T extends Magicable> {

    abstract List<T> getMagicables1();

    abstract List<? extends Magicable> getMagicables2();

    abstract List<Magicable> getMagicables3();
}

class MagicableWitch extends AbstractMagicable<Witch> {

    @Override
    List<Witch> getMagicables1() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    List<? extends Magicable> getMagicables2() {
        return getMagicables1();
    }

    @Override
    List<Magicable> getMagicables3() {
        return Collections.singletonList(new Witch());
    }   
}

class MagicableMagician extends AbstractMagicable<Magician> {

    @Override
    List<Magician> getMagicables1() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    List<? extends Magicable> getMagicables2() {
        return getMagicables1();
    }

    @Override
    List<Magicable> getMagicables3() {
        return Collections.singletonList(new Magician());
    }
}
```

1) T is used when you want to replace that with real name while using it. For example `class MagicableWitch extends AbstractMagicable<Witch>`.

Here `Witch` has replaced T and hence `abstract List<T> getMagicables1();` is changed to `List<Witch> getMagicables1()` in its concrete class.

2) ? is used when you class that will is to be replaced will be available at runtime.

3) `List<Magicable>` and `List<Witch>` are different even though `Witch implements Magicable`. The implementation is shown in `getMagicables3`
.

Answer (score 1):

In your first case, the abstract method is declared as using a generic type `<T extends Magicable>` which means that your method can return a list of Magicable or any type which implements it. In your implementation, your are returning the concrete type Magican which is a Magicable. You can safely ignore the warning and add `@SuppressWarning("unchecked")` to disable the warning. The thing to be aware is that any classes which extend your class, will be restricted to returning only lists of Magican.

In the second case, the declaration `List<T> list = getMagicables();` throws an error because your method doesn't return a `List<T>` but a `List<? extends Magicable'` which is not the same thing. Because of the way generics work, when you declare a return type which uses an unbound wildcard, any code which calls your method must have an accepted matching type, in your case like `List<? extends Magicable>` or `List<?>`.

Regarding the third case, your abstract method returns a `List<Magicable>` while your implementation returns a `List<Magic>`. This may seem counterintuitive, but you can't do something like this with generics in Java: `List<Magicable> list = ArrayList<Magic>`. This may seem weird since arrays allow you to declare something like `Magicable[] magics = new Magican[3];`. This is a common misconception because arrays are covariant while generics are invariant. What covariant means is that if you have two classes `Super` and `Sub extends Super`, `Sub[] is a subtype of Super[]`. For generics, because they are invariant, there is no relationship between those two, a `List<Sub>` is not a subtype of `List<Super>`.

If you want to return the generic type, just use the same type declaration as the first case `protected <T extends Magicable> List<T> getMagicable()` in the classes which extend your abstract class. It is a very bad idea to use wildcards in the returned type since you force your class users to use wildcards in their List variable declarations.